# Cordova - Open native email app from button click

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

When writing a native IOS app for example, you can open the native "Mail" app from a button click within an app. The email will come up pre-filled with certain data (send-to address, subject, body, etc.).

How can I simulate this across all devices using HTML5/Javascript in my cordova app?

Comment: you can also try [this plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using HTML5, you can do this with an anchor tag in your `.html` file. Here is an example:

```
<a href="mailto:email@gmail.com?subject=Example Subject 
&body=Thanks for the help!">Send an email</a>
```

This will work across all devices and resort to native functionality to handle the email task.

Answer (score 7):

Also, since cordova 3.6.3 you alo need to include the following permission in your config.xml.

```
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```